# Stop SharedPreferences to sync to new device

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have bought a new Pixel and noticed the apps have been automatically installed those I had my old phone. But also I noticed all the SharedPreferences have been also synchronized from my old device.

Is there anyway I can stop only the synchronizing the SharedPreferences data during new device registration for my app

Comment: Depends on the phone, but just go to settings then apps then it should be something like "clear data."

Comment: I am looking to do from code